# rxjs and SignalR - wait for async notification of background operation

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, rxjs, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to rewrite a piece of code properly with rxjs operators.
What the code does is: perform an http call to a webapi controller, which returns a Guid as the id of the long running background operation that is going to be performed on the server. When the operation will be complete, the server will signal the client via SignalR that such operation is complete, and the client side code will resume (until then, it will result as "waiting for a response").

The original snippet is the following:

```
this._service
    .myHttpCall(parameter1)
    .subscribe(
        operationId => {
            let sub = this._notifierHub.onOperationSuccess
                .subscribe(data => {
                    if (operationId !== data.operationId)
                        return;
                    this.notifySuccess();
                    sub.unsubscribe();
                    sub2.unsubscribe();
                });
            let sub2 = this._notifierHub.onOperationFailure
                .subscribe(data => {
                    if (operationId !== data.operationId)
                        return;
                    this.notifyFailure();
                    sub2.unsubscribe();
                    sub.unsubscribe();
                });
        }
    );
```

this._notifier is an Angular service that exposes a Subject as an Observable, and emits everytime the SignalR HubConnection emits.

What I would like to achieve is integrating the management of operation Id into the myHttpCall method, so that from the calling component's point of view the http call will be complete not when the operation id is returned, but when the actual operation is marked as complete via SignalR.

What I'd like to write is something like:

```
myHttpCall(parameter1: any) {
    const url = `${this.action("MyHttpCall")}`;
    const body = { parameter1: parameter1 };
    this._http
        .post(url, body, { responseType: "text" })
        .switchMap(operationId => {
            const successObservable = this._notifier
                .onOperationSuccess
                .filter(data => data.operationId === operationId);
            const failureObservable = this._notifier
                .onOperationFailure
                .filter(data => data.operationId === operationId);
            return <what?!>
}
```

What should be the method body so that I can then write, from the caller, this:

```
this._service
    .myHttpCall(parameter1)
    .subscribe(
        () => this.notifySuccess(),
        () => this.notifyFailure(),
        () => console.log("HttpCall completed")
    );
```

?

Comment: I'd recommend trying to utilizing a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject) such as an [AsyncSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#asyncsubject). You can use `next()` or `error()` to send success/error within the `subscribe()` respectively to observers consuming the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [`race`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race) operator inside your switchMap.

> The observable to emit first is used.

```
...switchMap(operationId => {
            const successObservable = this._notifier
                .onOperationSuccess
                .filter(data => data.operationId === operationId);
            const failureObservable = this._notifier
                .onOperationFailure
                .filter(data => data.operationId === operationId);

            return race(successObservable, failureObservable);
}
```

Comment: This is quite close to what I need, but, the onOperationSuccess and onOperationFailure observables are actually Subjects exposed as observables. So if my service returns one of these from a method call that resembles a normal http call, the caller will not unsubscribe from the subject and there will be memory leaks. e.g.:
this._service.doOperationAsync.subscribe(() => console.log("Success!"), () => console.log("Error!")); <-- need to unsubscribe!